# Android store, fetch and display from sqlite db

Tags: android-layout

```
  **Activity.java**
  public class Next11 extends Activity {
  ListView listView;
  SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
  UserDBhelper userDBhelper;
   Cursor cursor;
    ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;
   @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next11);
    listView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
   listDataAdapter = 
    new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_layout);   
    listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
    userDBhelper= new UserDBhelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = userDBhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = userDBhelper.getinfo(sqLiteDatabase);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String address,body,time;
            address=cursor.getString(0);
            body=cursor.getString(1);
            time=cursor.getString(2);
            DataProvider dataProvider = 
            new  DataProvider(address,body,time);
            listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
      }







  **row_layout.xml**
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android=
  "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="40dp">
  <TextView 
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:text="Sender"
    android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView 
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text4"
    android:text="Address"
    android:gravity="center"/>

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:text="Time"
    android:gravity="center"/>
   </LinearLayout>



   LOGCAT
          04-14 16:07:03.756: E/Database operations(16905):
          Database created/opened
        04-14 16:07:03.979: E/Database operations(16905): inserted
        04-14 16:07:59.886: E/Database operations(16905):
        Database created/opened
       04-14 16:07:59.921: E/ArrayAdapter(16905): 
       You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
     04-14 16:07:59.934: D/AndroidRuntime(16905): Shutting down VM
    04-14 16:07:59.959: E/AndroidRuntime(16905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   04-14 16:07:59.959: E/AndroidRuntime(16905): 
   Process:    com.example.sms, PID: 16905
  04-1416:07:59.959:E/AndroidRuntime(16905):
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a  TextView
    04-14 16:07:59.959: E/AndroidRuntime(16905):
   atandroid.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource
    (ArrayAdapter.java:393)
     04-14 16:07:59.959: E/AndroidRuntime(16905):   
      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
```

I am fetching data from sqlite db and displaying it in a multi column list view. But the app stops working before going to the display activity. And where do I check the db and inserted values? What is the solution?

Comment: paste the stacktrace from the logs, otherwise it can be just anything

Comment: @khusrav - Hey its working now. Can u tell me how to extract the amt(credited/debited) that cms along with a bank msg?